# How to perform azure storage service blob undelete using java sdk?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

How to perform azure storage service blob **undelete** operation using java sdk, when soft-delete enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use the latest version of azure-storage dependency library: azure-storage:8.0.0. You may not find the **BlobListingDetails.DELETED** enum value in the older versions.

Here is the code snippet.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(ConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
for (ListBlobItem listBlobItem : container.listBlobs(null, true, EnumSet.of(BlobListingDetails.DELETED), null,
    null)) {
CloudBlockBlob blobItem = (CloudBlockBlob) listBlobItem;

    if (blobItem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("blob-file-undelete.txt")) {
        blobItem.undelete();
        System.out.println("\nUndeleted the blob :" + blob.getName());
    }
}
```